# Equivalent for emplace and reserve functions in C program

Tags: c++, c, vector, size-t, emplace

I am trying to convert the following piece of code from C++ to C.

I created an array, but I'm not sure what can be a precise replacement for `emplace()` and `reserve()` and for `size_t`, what can be done in this case?

```
template<size_t X>
Student(float const(&rollnums)[X][5])
{
   class.reserve(X);
   for(size_t i =0; i< X; i++)
   {
      class.emplace(class.end(), rollnums[i];
   }
```

Where:

```
typedef struct _student
{
   std::vector<float> class;

}student;
```

Comment: Perhaps before focusing on the implementation of `emplace` and `reserve`, you should (in typical C style) focus on the data structure first.  To replace a `std::vector`, you would need to manage a pointer, an allocated size, and a used size.

Comment: `emplace` just builds it in place; this is the natural default in C.

Comment: To convert you need to rewrite the code completely. Not try to translate.

Comment: `emplace` and `reserve` primarily exist to avoid redundant constructor calls. C has no constructors, so this is pretty moot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact equivalent, but the closest analogue to `std::vector::reserve` in C is the standard library function `realloc`, and the closest analogue to `std::vector::emplace` is to cast the pointer to desired type, indirect through it, and assign the lvalue.

P.S. `_student` identifier is reserved to the language implementation in the file scope (in C) and in the global namespace (in C++). You should use another identifier. Also `class` is a keyword in C++ and cannot be used as an identifier.